# What is the result of List.OrderBy(), if multiple entries have the same value?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I am getting a strange behavior with the `OrderBy()` Method of `Lists`.

Imagine you have a List and each Person has `Firstname`, `Lastname` and `Gender`.
If all People in this list are of `Gender` `"m"`, I will get a different sorting after each call of

```
list.OrderBy(p => p.Gender)
```

But I don't want my list to jump around on each and every refresh. Any idea on this?

Comment: You don't get a different order since [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) is using a stable sort. Do you use a database driven provider like `Linq-To-Entities`? _"This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements that have the same key."_

Comment: If all persons in the list are male, why do you order the list by it?

Comment: yes, it is database driven and the objects are created new every 15 seconds. maybe that's the cause.

Comment: It was just an example. Imagine you have one female in the list. It will always appear at the top. But all the male entries will order randomly in themselves (in my case)

Comment: I think it can't be said often or LOUD enough: The LINQ sorts are __stable__, so they don't mess up preordered elements.. Finally :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ThenBy()` to sort it using other properties if Gender is same. Like this:

```
list.OrderBy(p=>p.Gender).ThenBy(p=>p.FirstName);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution. But I am nevertheless wondering how C# orders the entries or why the order is always different.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `Gender` `m` is a string type and there are many result using `m`, this is not a orderable entity. So when you try to order using this property then it orders randomly using `m`. Try to order by using something else which have some orderable entities, like `FirstName`.

```
list.OrderBy(p=>p.Firstname);
```

or

```
list.OrderBy(p=>p.Lastname);
```

or

```
list.OrderBy(p=>p.Gender).ThenBy(p=>p.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by all the fields, like:

```
list.OrderBy(x=>x.Gender).ThenBy(x=>x.FirstName).ThenBy(x=>x.LastName);
```